# Month not showing in APA citation

Tags: biblatex, biber, apa-style

I'm using biblatex-apa and this example should put the month after the year as in (Gilbert, 1987, may) but I get (Gilbert, 1987).

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
@article{gilbert87,
    title = {Terrifying guitar 101},
    journal = {Guitar player},
    author = {Gilbert, Paul},
    month = may,
    year = {1987},
    pages = {99}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[
    style=apa,
    backend=biber
]{biblatex}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[british]{babel}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}

\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}

Here is som text \parencite{gilbert87}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se and thanks for posting a minimal document!

Comment: Why do you expect it to be "(Gilbert, 1987, may)"? "(Gilbert, 1987)" seems perfectly correct. And if there were two works by Gilbert in 1987, I'd expect to find "(Gilbert, 1987a)" and "(Gilbert, 1987b)". Still, Alan is correct that you should use `date={1987-05}` instead of the `year = {1987}` and `month = may` as you do.

Comment: Just to clarify, I had mentioned that the month field should be numeric, but then edited my comment.

Answer (score 2):

By adding a second bib entry `gilbert88` to the `bib` file like

```
@article{gilbert88,
    title   = {Terrifying guitar 101},
    journal = {Guitar player},
    author  = {Gilbert, Paul},
    date    = {1988-05},
    pages   = {100},
}
```

with an `biblatex` conform `date` field instead the old `year` and `month` fields (`date = {1988-05}`) you get with the following MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{gilbert87,
    title   = {Terrifying guitar 101},
    journal = {Guitar player},
    author  = {Gilbert, Paul},
    month   = may,
    year    = {1987},
    pages   = {99},
}
@article{gilbert88,
    title   = {Terrifying guitar 101},
    journal = {Guitar player},
    author  = {Gilbert, Paul},
    date    = {1988-05},
    pages   = {100},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
    style=apa,
    backend=biber
]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}

Here is some text~\parencite{gilbert87} and~\parencite{gilbert88}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

the following result:

[image: resulting bibliography]

As you can see the new bib entry with year 1988 in field `date = {1988-05}` gives the bibliography entry you wish.

To get the month displayed with `\parencite` you need to redefine that command with `\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}`.

See the following MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{gilbert87,
    title   = {Terrifying guitar 101},
    journal = {Guitar player},
    author  = {Gilbert, Paul},
    month   = may,
    year    = {1987},
    pages   = {99},
}
@article{gilbert88,
    title   = {Terrifying guitar 101},
    journal = {Guitar player},
    author  = {Gilbert, Paul},
    date    = {1988-05},
    pages   = {100},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
    style=apa,
    backend=biber
]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]%
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}\setunit{\nameyeardelim}\printfield{month}} % <============
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:post}}


\begin{document}

Here is some text~\parencite{gilbert87} 
and~\parencite[prenote][postnote]{gilbert88} 
and~\parencite*[prenote][postnote]{gilbert88}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is there way to show the month in the cite too? Some universities wants it that way.

Comment: @mikaelaspsomkane If you like my answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).